# Add click handler on all A tags using jQuery

Tags: jquery

Trying to add a click event handler on all A tags using `jQuery`. Tried with and without the `document.ready`, also used `document.getElementsByTagName("a");` without luck. It's logging '`document is ready`' but doesn't attach the event listeners. Thank you for the help!

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   console.log('document is ready');
    $('a').each(function(){
        $(this).addEventListener("click", 
            function (event) {
                console.log(event);
                event.preventDefault();
            }, false
        );
    });
});
```

Comment: your mixing native javascript and jquery, pick one don't mix them....

Comment: Did you check your javascript console?  It should be showing you `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).addEventListener is not a function`

Comment: The type error wasn't in the console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using jquery selectors you don't actually need to manually attach a click handler to each element - rather you can attach the handler to any element that matches the selector.

`$('a')` will match **any** `<a>` tag on the page, so it should be enough for you in this case.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   console.log('document is ready');
    $('a').click(function( event ){
      console.log(event);
    });
});
```

Within your click handler, the `this` context will be set to the element that was actually clicked.

```
    $('a').click(function( event ){
      // "this" is the <a> that triggered the event.
      // "$(this)" is the same element in a jquery wrapper.
    });
```

Comment: Thank you for this response. In addition to $('a') I needed to make sure the data was loaded. The document was ready, but the data wasn't there. I'm using isomorphic fetch, so chaining an additional 
.then(() => {
            $('a').click(function( event ){
                event.preventDefault();
            console.log(event, this);
            });
    }) is what worked in my case.

Comment: Makes sense :) Glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   console.log('document is ready');
    $('a').each(function(){
        $(this).click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
    
    }); 
 
    });
});
```

Comment: No need to loop over all the elements one by one. A click handler can be defined once for all elements that match a given selector - `$( 'a' )`.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
$(document).on("click", 'a', function (event) {
            alert(event);
            event.preventDefault();
        });
```

Comment: Any specific reason not to use the `click()` shorthand method?

Comment: ` $('a').click("click", function (event) {
            alert(event);
            //event.preventDefault();
        });`

Comment: pls ignore above comment

Comment: You can delete your comments - there is a little "X"  on the right side of the comment.

Comment: `$('a').click("click", function (event) {
            alert(event);
            //event.preventDefault();
        });`  

Its not raising alert event at my end

Comment: That code is wrong. You don't have to supply 'click' to the `click()` function - it is redundant and not a valid argument to the function.

Comment: `$('a').click(function (event) {
            alert(event);
            //event.preventDefault();
        });`  

Its not raising alert event at my end

Comment: Hi Lix, I am unable to delete comments. As I don't have such reputation points

Comment: you can always delete your own comments.